# Convert SharePoint site group members to Office 365 group members for already connected site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

We have created some Office 365 group with one same owner (Admin account). 
Site Members and owners was only set in sharePoint groups because the need was only to access sharepoint site(not planner,teams ..etc).

Now, we want to programatically convert site owners to o365 group owners and site members to office 365 members. 
Is there an easy way to do it ?